# HDInsight VM initialization error when loading data

Tags: hadoop, jvm, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to run [this getting started sample](http://gettingstarted.hadooponazure.com/loadingData.html)  for loading data into my single node HDInsight hadoop cluster. When I run the sample I get the error as shown below:

```
c:\Hadoop\GettingStarted>powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -F importdata.
ps1 w3c
Attempting to import scenario w3c

Path
----
C:\Hadoop\GettingStarted\w3c
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException:
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Charset.java:273)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Charset.java:458)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:437)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(Charset.java:579)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:37)

        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:94)
        at java.io.PrintStream.<init>(PrintStream.java:100)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1092)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is related with file write permission when creating data file on your machine.